# Different implementation of an Interface along with additional parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface, proxy

I am designing an interface for 2 distinct implementations as follows:

1. Perform operations without client credentials ( for my local applications)
2. Perform operations using security token. (for web applications)

Interfaces are as follows :

```
interface IContactService 
{        
    void Add(Contact c);
    void Update(Contact c);
}

interface IProxy 
{
     string Token { get; set; }
     void SetToken(string token);
}
```

and below are the implementations :

```
public class ContactBusinessImpl : IContactService
{

    private IContactService _contactService;

    public ContactBusinessImpl(IContactService contactService) {
        _contactService = contactService;
    }

    public void Add(Contact c)
    {
        _contactService.Add(c);
    }

    public void Update(Contact c)
    {
        _contactService.Update(c);
    }
}

public class ContactBusinessProxyImpl : IContactService , IProxy
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public void SetToken(string token)
    {
        Token = token;
    }
    public void Add(Contact c)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(Token);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.PostAsync("api/add", stringContent);
    }     

    public void Update(Contact c)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(Token);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.PostAsync("api/update", stringContent);
    }
}
```

Earlier I was using token as a parameter for each method (`Add(Contact c,string token)`) which was not acceptable.

Now I am okay with above approach, **but it seems like without SetToken I cant do anything in proxy implementation**.

Since I am using DI to instantiate classes for can't go for Adapter pattern like `ContactBusinessProxyImpl(string token)`.

Is there any better approach or pattern can be used here?

Comment: hi there - if I undestand your problem correctly, then you NEED a token in order to make ContactBusinessImpl  actually work - and you don't want to pass in the token as a parameter in the void Add() and void Update() methods - am i understanding you correctly here?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes you are right.

Comment: few more questions: (i) you are injecting the token into the concrete classes - via a property or method etc? (ii) do you have the token available  upon instantiation of the concrete classes?

Comment: (i) yes i am injecting token at run time so i neee to use property, or a variable with setter method. (ii) no

Comment: Finally - can you provide more detail on the class and method which actually obtains the token?

Comment: actually its a proxy and all the methods required token to call remote service.

Comment: if that's the case, what is the added benefit of using the ContactBusinessImpl - because it definitely needs the token - which is exactly what the ContactBusinessProxyImpl does - the ContactBusinessImpl seems like a wrapper for the proxy implementation without adding any additional benefits and seems redundant. Why not get rid of the wrapper and simply use the proxy implementation in its place?

Answer (score 6):

> Since I am using DI to instantiate classes

I have to disappoint you... there is no DI in your code. The only service you are using is instantiated inside the class using it:

> ```
> private ContactService _contactService = new ContactService();
> ```

DI would be if you passed it to `ContactBusinessImpl` via constructor.

---

> ```
> public string Token { get; set; }
>
> public void SetToken(string token)
> {
>     Token = token;
> }
> ```

We don't usually do that. A value is either a mandatory one, then we use a constructor so the user must provide it or it's optional so we create a get/set property for it and don't enforce it via constructor. Having a method that sets a property that has a setter is pointless.

---

> ```
> public void Add(Contact c)
> {
>     var client = new HttpClient();
>     client.SetBearerToken(Token);
>     var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
>     client.PostAsync("api/add", stringContent);
> }
> ```

Creating `HttpClient` on each call is a bad idea. At some point you'll [run out of sockets](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

---

Comment: You are correct about the Dependency injection and Http Client instantiation. Thanks for pointing out. Also Agree with  "A value is either a mandatory one, then we use a constructor".  But my concern is  how to use 'ContactBusinessProxyImpl ' and 'ContactBusinessImpl ' for 'IContactService' effectively.